# WordPress: multiple search terms or join results from multiple WP_Queries

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the following code:

```
$args = array(
    's'                 => 'Apple',
    'cat'               => 80,
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => date,
    'order'             => desc,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $query->found_posts.'<br /><br />';
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
        echo the_time("Y.m.d"); echo ': '; echo the_title(); echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

It searches category 80 for any post that contains the word **Apple** and then successfully outputs the list of such posts like

```
2

2016.10.10: Apple pie
2016.10.01: Apple juice
```

If I also want to display all the posts that contains the word **Banana** then I just repeat the code with `'s' => 'Apple'` replaced with `'s' => 'Banana'` and get something like

```
1

2016.10.05: Banana fresh
```

Quite easy until I want to output both search results using the single list like

```
3

2016.10.10: Apple pie
2016.10.05: Banana fresh
2016.10.01: Apple juice
```

Here I need your help as I have no idea how to achieve that.

So far I've tried

```
$args = array(
    's'                 => array('Apple','Banana'),
    'cat'               => 80,
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => date,
    'order'             => desc,
);
```

and

```
$args = array(
    array('s' => 'Apple',),
    array('s' => 'Banana',),
    'cat'               => 80,
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => date,
    'order'             => desc,
);
```

Both return all posts from the given category even if there is only one element in the subarray, so it seems `'s'` couldn't be put in a subarray or contain array as the argument. Or I have mistyped somewhere but I can not catch where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was waiting for the ready answer, I was also researching the PHP manual and WP Codex, so I've ended up with the following **working** solution.

In case someone would search for the answer for the same question, here it is:

```
<?php

// Searching for posts with "Apple" in their content within category with the id 80
$args_apple = array('s' => 'Apple', 'cat' => 80, 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$query_apple = new WP_Query( $args_apple );
wp_reset_query();

// Searching for posts with "Banana" in their content within category with the id 80
$args_banana = array('s' => 'Banana', 'cat' => 80, 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$query_banana = new WP_Query( $args_banana );
wp_reset_query();

// Searching for posts with "Orange" in their content within category with the id 80
$args_orange = array('s' => 'Orange', 'cat' => 80, 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$query_orange = new WP_Query( $args_orange );
wp_reset_query();

// Joining results, excluding duplicates with wrapping array_merge() into array_unique()
$result = new WP_Query();
$result->posts = array_unique(array_merge(
    $query_apple->posts,
    $query_banana->posts,
    $query_orange->posts
), SORT_REGULAR); // While PHP manual states this parameter is
                  // optional for array_unique(), in this case
                  // it is obligatory

// Showing the number of results
$result->post_count = count( $result->posts );
echo $result->post_count.'<br /><br />';

// Sorting results by date
usort($result->posts, 'order_by_date');
function order_by_date( $a, $b ) {
    $a_date = $a->post_date;
    $b_date = $b->post_date;
    return ( strcmp($a_date, $b_date ) > 0 ) ? -1 : 1; // Sort descending
//  return ( strcmp($a_date, $b_date ) > 0 ) ? 1 : -1; // Sort ascending
}

// The search results output loop
if ( $result->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $result->have_posts() ) { $result->the_post();
        // Start making your own output
        echo the_time("Y.m.d");
        echo ': ';
        echo the_title();
        echo '<br />';
        // Stop making your own output
    }
}
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

The only thing I don't like with all code above is an extra function to sort merged array items. But I've spent a good half of the day to find a way to sort items of merged array with internal parameters, with no success.

The result is like

```
7

2016.10.21: Banana
2016.10.15: Sliced orange
2016.10.09: Banana fresh
2016.10.07: Apple juice
2016.10.05: Apple pie
2016.10.03: Orange
2016.10.01: Apple
```

The number of merged arrays seems to be unlimited or so, just don't forget to use unique `$args_name` and `$query_name` for each `WP_Query()`.

And always close each query with `wp_reset_query()`.

Comment: What if i want to sort by a numeric meta query field like price? How it should be done?

Answer (score 5):

While your solution clearly works, I'd like to submit another possible solution that leverages the filters that WordPress offers.  In this way, I believe this solution is more consistent with "The WordPress Way":

```
// Hook into the WP_Query filter to modify the search query
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'make_search_any_terms', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Function to convert search to "any" terms instead of "all" terms.
 * WordPress automatically passes in the two arguments.
 * 
 * @param string $search
 * @param WP_Query $query
 *
 * @return string
 */
function make_search_any_terms( $search, $query ) {
    // If it's not a search, then do nothing
    if ( empty( $query->is_search ) ) {
        return $search;
    }

    global $wpdb;

    $search_terms = get_query_var( 'search_terms' );

    // This code adapted from WP_Query "parse_search" function
    $search    = '';
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ( $search_terms as $term ) {
        $like                        = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $term ) . '%';
        $q['search_orderby_title'][] = $wpdb->prepare( "$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s", $like );

        $like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $term ) . '%';
        $search .= $wpdb->prepare( "{$searchand}(($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s) OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE %s))", $like, $like );
        // This is the significant change - originally is "AND", change to "OR"
        $searchand = ' OR ';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
        }
    }

    return $search;
}
```

To use it with a SINGLE search query:

```
$args = array(
    's'                 => 'Apple Banana Orange',
    // ...
);

$results = WP_Query( $args );
```

You will get all results that have **either** apple **or** banana **or** orange.

In this way, you could have a single query and a single set of results, and simply loop through it.

**NOTE:**  The above code is normally put in your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment instead of edit. ) Anyway I just wanted to add that the function you've provided has pushed me to the solution of how to limit the search only by post content. So thanks a lot! ))

Comment: Old post but for the love of me, I can't make this work. Has anything changed in the Wordpress core that would not allow this to work any longer?

Comment: @scooterlord - no, things should still work.  If you post a new question with your specific code and let me know by commenting me, I'll gladly take a look at it.

Comment: Actually I managed to get it to work! A million thanks for the offer though!

Comment: What if i want to search a phrase? Like part of a string. How it should be done. Its not working for me. Any help appreciated.For example i have a title ‘i am the best in the world’ and a title ‘its five in the morning’ how can i search the phrase ‘in the world’ along with phrase ‘five in the’?

Comment: @stefanosn - that's a new question.  If you post a question and then come back here and post a link to it, I'll gladly take a look at it.

Comment: thanks ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120983/search-multiple-keywords-with-wp-query-using-one-query/57122026#57122026