# search multiple keywords with wp_query using one query

Tags: wordpress

I use this wp_query to get results for a specific keyword and sort by price. I need to search multiple keywords at the same time and return results and sort them by product price. How is this possible using one wp_query?

For example there are three title records:

I am fine here thanks
   I am fine thanks
   I am fineeee now

If I search for the text ‘m fine’, I should get all three rows as result.
If I search ‘m f’ I should get all rows as results.
If I search ‘m fine t’ i should get only second row as result.
If I search ‘e t’ i should get first two rows as result.

Now if I search for the phrase ‘e n’ **and at the same time** the phrase ‘e t’, I should get all three rows again as result. If I search ‘fine here’ **and at the same time** ‘fine t’ I should get two first rows as result and so on. **NOTE:** I will programmatically add the multiple phrases to the search.

```
 $args = [
        // this does not work.
        // should be treated as two exact phrases: "fine here" and "fine t"
        's'           => "fine here+fine t",
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'sentence'    => true,
        'paged'       => $paged,
        'meta_query'  => [
            'product_price'  => [ 
                'key' => 'product_price', 
                'value' => '0', 
                'compare' => '>' , 
                'type'=>'NUMERIC'
            ]
        ],
        'orderby'     => 'product_price',
        'order'       => 'ASC'
    ];
```

Comment: Please provide desired sample _input_ and sample _results_.  (eg, a list of results that should match, and examples of what should not match)

Comment: For example i have three title records

1. I am fine here thanks
2. I am fine thanks
3. I am fineeee now

If i search for the text ‘m fine’ i should get all three rows as result. If i search ‘m f’ again i should get all rows as results. If i search ‘m fine t’ i should get only second row as result. If i search ‘e t’ i should get first two rows as result.

Now if i search ‘e n’ and ‘e t’ i should get all three rows again as result. If i search ‘fine here’ and ‘fine t’ i should get two first rows as result and so on...

Comment: So it sounds like you want to find the _exact_ match of a string, as opposed to searching for the appearance of the different words in the phrase regardless of whether they are adjacent or not.

Comment: yes and sort them by a numeric meta value.

Comment: OK.  Can you update the question to reflect your example in the comments? For example, the `s` argument in your question is _different_ than your comment example, so it creates a bit of confusion.

Comment: done updated to 'fine here' & 'fine t’

Comment: It's still confusing.  You say if you search `e n` and `e t` - how do you search *two* phrases at once?

Comment: i dont know how. this is what i am  searching for...

Comment: No, I mean from the front-end.  How do you enter two separate phrases to search at the same time?  Entering multiple _keywords_ into a search is easy - one input, each "word" in the input is a keyword.  Entering multiple _key phrases_ is what I'm asking: how will your user enter BOTH `e n` and `e t`, such that the system will recognize them as two separate key phrases?

Comment: The user will write the first one and tap search. I will add the rest at the back end using code.

Comment: OK.  Give me some time to think / research this.  It's not simple to accomplish, and other answers / resources don't quite do this.

Comment: i understand thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're using the search parameters (`s`) of WP_Query to query posts via keyword.

More keywords can be added to the query by using the `+` character.

Example:

```
$args = array(
    's' => 'keyword1+keyword2',
    ...
```

Comment: Hmmm but i want to search using a phrase...because my keywords are like this “i want this” , “i want that” . Its not a continues word like iwantthis or iwantthat. The words i need to search have spaces. How it should be? And thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the help here, do you happen to know the following:

 - Are these keywords exclusive or inclusive (i.e. do multiple keywords need BOTH matches to return or EITHER)? My testing suggests the former (BOTH) but I don't see docs specifying the behaviour, or how to reverse it...
 - Can you append excluded keywords like so `foo+bar-nope` (that would return for `foo`/`bar` but not if `nope` exists?  

Thanks!